# JAXB case sensitive class generation

Tags: java, jaxb, standards, case-sensitive

I want to create classes from a standard schema [learning object model](http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/lomv1.0/). The schema appears to be broken due to a lowercased type. Is there any way that I can generate classes with jaxb in a "case insensitve" mode?

Here is the problem where the conflict comes out:

```
<xs:complexType name="Duration">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <xs:element name="duration" type="DurationValue"/>
     <xs:element name="description" type="description"/>
     <xs:group ref="ex:customElements"/>
    </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType> 

<xs:complexType name="duration">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Duration">
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="ag:duration"/>
       <xs:attributeGroup ref="ex:customAttributes"/>
     </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

I have rename the "duration" tag to "customDuration" and I have change the references as well and it works.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by 'schema appears to be broken due to a lowercased type'. Could you provide (perhaps simplified) example what doesn't work for you?

Comment: there are is a complex type called "Duration" and another one that extends it called "duration". Jaxb shows the error: (Relevant to above error) another "Duration" is generated from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should change the schema in order to have `Duration` and `duration_`, generate JAXB objects and then change your JAXB classes generated in order to adapt them to the origina WSDL. For example, in Java:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Duration")
protected String duration;

@XmlElement(name = "duration")
protected String duration_;
```

(I have simplified the types in the example). Hope anyway you find a better solution.

Comment: Thank you, I have already done that and it works. I was wondering why Jaxb doesnt have any case insesitive flag, where I could generate two classes: "Duration.java" and "duration.java". thanks again

Comment: I think that it is complicated because that would be not aligned with the Java Code Conventions. I started to work with JABX few weeks ago and I have had problems like you. I feel that lots of existing WSDL are not prepare for JAX-WS

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered but Hope this will help some one else , use -XautoNameResolution so that new classes will be generated whenever it encounters two elements with same name (Case insensitive). I used it as following

xjc -d src -p com.sample -wsdl somewsdl.wsdl -XautoNameResolution

Comment: This parameter usage (also in maven) is here: https://gist.github.com/barbietunnie/69310de4366039411ad11e367542155e